# using c++ string class functions to display “gene substrings” from a longer original Genome string

Tags: c++, string, function, class

Please help. 
I'm testing my gene finder program with a sequence TGTGTGTATAT with start cap ATG added to front and ending cap TAA added to the end so I'm testing the genome ATGTGTGTGTATATTAA since not including the caps the sequence isn't a multiple of 3 characters in length it therefore doesn't contain any genes and should display

"no gene is found"

the black cout window does popup
but it displays nothing

```
//Date: 
//purpose:  find Genes and cout found genes

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string genome = "ATGTGTGTGTATATTAA"; //testing this string
        /*cout << "Enter a genome string: ";
    cin >> genome;*/

        int geneCounter = 0;


while(!genome.empty())  //enters loop if strings not empty
{


if(genome.find("ATG",0) == string::npos) //genome.find("ATG",0,3) should return npos if no ATG is found right? 
{   
    if(geneCounter == 0)
    {
    cout << "no gene is found";  
    genome.clear(); 
    }
}
else
{
    int startGene = genome.find("ATG",0); //ATG is not part of gene just a front endcap to genes
    int endGene = min(min(genome.find("TAG"), genome.find("TAA")), genome.find("TGA"));//endcaps are TAG or TAA or TGA 
                                                                                       //finds location of (1+ gene end) 


    string currentGene = genome.substr(startGene + 3, endGene - (startGene +3)); //puts copy of gene in substring

    if((currentGene.length() % 3) == 0)
    {
        geneCounter += 1;
        cout << currentGene <<endl;//a gene is a multiple of three characters so if its a gene I cout the gene
    }

    endGene += 3;
    genome.erase(0, endGene); //should erase the gene I just "cout"displayed 
                                                //and its front ATG and its endcap and anything before its ATG

    //cout << genome; //testing: this should display the genome after the endcap of the last gene cause I erased all coming before 
}
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it wasn't a multiple of 3 to begin with, how does adding two length 3 caps make it a multiple of 3?  Sure, 11 isn't a multiple of 3, but neither is 17.

Comment: only the characters between the endcaps should be displayed in cout and only if the number of those characters between the endcaps is a multiple of 3.

Comment: the sequence I'm testing should cout "no gene is found"

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a perfect usecase for a clean regex solution. What are the exact rules for validating the gene string again?

Starts with ATG

Genes of three chars. What chars are allowed?

Ends with TTA

Using a regex like

```
^ATG([A-Z]{3})+TTA$
```

^ is the beginning of a row. ATG is a string to match exacly. ([A-Z]{3})+ is a matching group, means it will be extracted as found, with three charactera from A-Z. TTA is again an exact match. The plus meams only valid if at least one of this group was found.. $ is the end of the row.

Instead of [A-Z] you could use [ATGE] if only that are valid chars.

This should solve your problem completely. Giving you an iterator to all inner three char substrings, while length start and end are checked too.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: I don't believe my code should reject any characters in the gene which is to be displayed its suposed to find The starting cap ATG and the first ending cap(either TAA or TGA or TAG) which comes after this ATG in the string and then display the part of the string which is between the starting cap and subsequent ending cap. But before it displays this string it tests if this substring is a multiple of 3 characters long if it isn't it should display "no gene is found"

Comment: looks interesting but I don't know where exactly that ^ATG([A-Z]{3})+TAA$  Would go in my code. What i need to do to use that?

Comment: If you have to solve pattern matching problems often, is is definitely worth learning regex. I'll updatw the answer with more info but this here is one of my favorite tutorials on the topic (lynda.com is not feee but worth every cent) http://www.lynda.com/Regular-Expressions-tutorials/Using-Regular-Expressions/85870-2.html

Answer (score 0):

The first iteration of the while loop goes into the `else` block, and ends with

```
genome.erase(0, endGene);
```

This erases the entire genome, so when the `while` condition is checked,

```
while(!genome.empty())
```

`genome` is empty so the program exits.

Try just changing the while condition to:

```
while(true)
```

This may not be the end goal, but it may help steer you in the right direction.